# How to write a row into txt file

Tags: matlab

I've already read two rows from Excel using this code:

```
filename = 'myExample.xlsx';
columnB = xlsread(filename,'B:B')
```

and this is the result:

```
 raw =
```

Columns 1 through 4

```
[1]    'J0416'      'J0081 '          [-0.221000000000000]
[2]    'J0081  '    'J0011   '        [ 1.429200000000000]
[3]    'J0011  '    'J0700      '     [-1.713400000000000]
[4]    ' J0700 '    ' J0073   '       [-1.009600000000000]
[5]    ' J0073'     '  M0232     '    [ 1.835500000000000]
[6]    'M0232'      '  M0375   '      [12.486700000000001]
```

Column 5

```
[    17.405999999999999]
[1.326780000000000e+002]
[3.917520000000000e+002]
[6.486120000000000e+002]
[8.552070000000000e+002]
[1.185750000000000e+002]
```

How I can get this input to be written into a text file like the following?

```
       distance 1   distance 2
           -0.221       17.406
           1.4292      132.678
          -1.7134      391.752
          -1.0096      648.612
           1.8355      855.207
          12.4867      118.575
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use fopen to open a text file, fprintf to write data and fclose in the end

```
clear all
A = rand(10,2);
fileId = fopen('out.txt','w');
fprintf(fileId,'%s\t%s\n','distance1','distance2');
fprintf(fileId,'%f\t%f\n',A);
fclose(fileId);
```

Comment: or `dlmwrite` is another option.

Comment: Is 'A' representing for both distance1 and distance2? How to define 'A'?

Comment: How to define A? because when I use the coding I don't get the actual result.

Comment: what does your columnB look like?

Comment: back to 'raw' above, how I can define it as A?

Comment: A = [[raw{4,:}]' [raw{5,:}]'];

Comment: what about A = rand(10,2);?

Comment: it was just an example